# Expo Notification askAsync() - Is there a way to customize the message?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo, react-native-push-notification

I am using EXPO on a react native project and want to ask the user for push notification permission.

When I use the `const {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);` the message that appears is

> "Expo" would like to send you notifications. Notifications may include sounds, badges, alerts and icon badges. These can be configured in settings.

My end user doesn't know what "Expo" is, they just know the app name. Is there a way for me to customize the "Expo" part to the app name?

How have people handled this when their app is ejected and push to the app store?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? Currently facing the same situation.

Comment: @Scott I did. You can update your app.json file to include a custom icon and color etc with: `"notification": { "icon": "./assets/Logo.png" }` and then when you actually deploy with Expo you specify the name of your app and that name is what shows up in the push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in here: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/?redirected

Which says:

System permissions dialogs on iOS
If your app asks for system permissions from the user, e.g. to use the device's camera, or access photos, Apple requires an explanation for how your app makes use of that data. Expo will automatically provide a boilerplate reason for you, such as "Allow cool-app to access the camera", however these must be customized and tailored to your specific use case in order for your app to be accepted by the App Store. To do this, override these values using the ios.infoPlist key in app.json, for example:

"infoPlist": {
"NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to scan barcodes on event tickets."
},

The full list of keys Expo provides by default can be seen here. Unlike with Android, on iOS it is not possible to filter the list of permissions an app may request at a native level. This means that by default, your app will ship with all of these default boilerplate strings embedded in the binary. You can provide any overrides you want in the infoPlist configuration. Because these strings are configured at the native level, they will only be published when you build a new binary with expo build.

Answer (score -1):

You probably use Expo Go to develop your app , when you create standalone app (when you deploy the apk) it will show the app name that you specified in app.json.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).